# C++ Fstream Only Prints One Word

Tags: c++, fstream

This is a very strange issue. I'm trying to print a large text file, it's a Wikipedia entry. It happens to be the page on Velocity. So, when I tell it to print the file, it prints "In", when it should print "In physics, velocity is etc, etc etc". 
Here's the code I'm using to print out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

    int main()
        {
        ifstream wiki;
        wiki.open("./wiki/velocity.txt");
        char* wikiRead;
        wiki >> wikiRead;
        cout << wikiRead << endl;
        wiki.close();
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Why would you think an entire line would be read? The code above only asks for a single word to be printed. You may want to look into the `getline` function.

Comment: Thanks for humoring me, you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wiki >> wikiRead;
```

The default delimiter for stream is space, so when the stream encounters a space, it simply stops reading, that is why it reads only one word.

If you want the stream to read all words, the you've to use a loop as:

```
char* wikiRead = new char[1024]; //must allocate some memory!
while(wiki >> wikiRead)
{
   cout << wikiRead << endl;
}
wiki.close();
delete []wikiRead; //must deallocate the memory
```

This will print all the words in the file, each on a new line. Note if any of the word in the file is more than `1024` character long, then this program would invoke undefined behavior, and the program *might* crash. In that case, you've to allocate a bigger  chunk of memory.

But why use `char*` in the first place? In C++, you've better choice: Use `std::string`.

```
#include<string>

std::string word;
while(wiki >> word)
{
   cout << word << endl;
}
wiki.close();
```

Its better now.

If you want to read line-by-line, instead of word-by-word, then use `std::getline` as:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(wiki, line))
{
   cout << line << endl;
}
wiki.close();
```

This will read a complete line, even if the line contains spaces between the words, and will print each line a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the stream to read the (binary) value of a pointer (probably 4 bytes, depending on your machine architecture), then you ask it to print the text pointed to by those 4 bytes!

Comment: Not really, the code asks for reading the first word in the file, because **default delimter for stream is space**.

Comment: That'll teach me to answer questions in the middle of the night when I've got insomnia. You are still reading to an uninitialised pointer, though, so anything can happen.

Comment: Thank you all. You were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you ignored the compiler warning (most of the modern compiler warns you about using uninitialized variables). How about this?

```
    ifstream wiki;
    wiki.open("./wiki/velocity.txt");
    char wikiRead[255];
    wiki >> wikiRead;
    cout << wikiRead << endl;
    wiki.close();
```

Alternatively I'd suggest you to use `string` object with `getline` to get a single line of text.

```
string str;
getline(wiki, str);
```

Comment: The original code has given is also not reading the entire file? It's all up to him whether he should read entire file or not!

Comment: The Q is clear, OP wants to read the entire file, His code is not able to do so. You provided him a example of your own which does the same(Does not read the entire file). So I don't really know what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator applied to a `char *` reads only one word. Moreover, you're reading into an uninitialized pointer, which is not valid. Usually `std::string`, not `char *`, is used for string processing in C++.

If you only want to print the file's contents, you can hook the file's buffer directly to  `std::cout`:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream wiki("./wiki/velocity.txt");
    std::cout << wiki.rdbuf() << '\n';
}
```

If you want to put the contents into an automatically-allocated string, use `std::getline` with the delimiter disabled.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream wiki("./wiki/velocity.txt");
    std::string wiki_contents;
    getline( wiki, wiki_contents, '\0' /* do not stop at newline */ );

    std::cout << wiki_contents << '\n'; // do something with the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to read a large file, reading it block by block is a better way.

```
ifstream wiki;
wiki.open("./wiki/velocity.txt");
const int buf_size = 1024;
char* wikiRead = 0;
int cnt = 1;
do
{
   wikiRead = realloc( wikiRead, bufsize*cnt );
   wiki.Read( wikiRead + (bufSize*(cnt-1)), buf_size ); //appends to reallocated memory
   cnt++;
}while( !wiki.eof())
wikiRead[(bufSize*(cnt-2)) + wiki.gcount() + 1] = '\0'; // null termination.
wiki.Close();
cout << wikiRead;
delete[] wikiRead;
```

Comment: This is a very "C" way of going about things.  See the less error-prone solutions, such as the one shown by @Nawaz.  Also, you shouldn't mix `malloc/realloc/free` with `new/delete`! http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/newandmalloc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `operator>>` is designed to only read one word at a time. If you want to read lines, use `getline`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream wiki;
    wiki.open("./wiki/velocity.txt");

    string   wikiRead;

    while (getline(wiki, wikiRead))
    {
        cout << wikiRead << endl;
    }

    wiki.close();
}
```